# Change the sliding bar color on alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'd like to change the sliding bar color on an alert dialog when you have a listview. Actually, I do understand how to change the background color by doing this :

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(fragmentActivity, R.style.AlertDialogCustom)).create();
```

And then :

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:background">#d3d3d3</item>
</style>
```

But I don't find anything to change color of the sliding bar on the right.

Comment: What "sliding button" are you referring to?

Comment: are you want to button color of dialog buttons?

Comment: If you are refering to `AlertDialog` buttons try `android:colorAccent`

Comment: I mean the button on right which is visible when you scroll the alert dialog when you have a listview inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Listview property as:

```
android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style"
```

Here custom_scroll_style is a xml file under the drawable folder. Lets create the custom_scroll_style.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<gradient
android:angle="45"
android:endColor="#FF3401"
android:centerColor="#ff5c33"
android:startColor="#FF3401" />
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
<size android:width="4dp"/>
<padding
android:left="0.5dp"
android:right="0.5dp" />
</shape>
```

Hope it will help you out.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry ! is not really a button. I'm talking about the right scrolling bar on the right when you have a listview. I want to change the color of this. Let me edit my question.

Comment: Ok great ! I will try this and give you a feedback then.

Comment: Your solution is really great. However I couldn't use setAdapter directly wih the alertDialog. I had to use setView with the alertdialog and inflate a listview inside with its own adapter.